# Mistake in years of work in resume

Tags: interviewing, resume, mistakes

I have made a mistake in my resume. I have worked in one company on different positions. I have written in the resume wrong years for two consequent positions, but not the latest one within the company.

I have corrected the mistake, but I have send wrong version of my resume to couple jobs applications. If I will get an interview, how should I address this mistake? What is the best way to discuss it with HR, I mean, should I mention it from the beginning or it is okey to tell about it at the end of interview?
I applied for one job via online form on the company site. So, i can't download updated interview, only sent it to the HR manager. What should I do in this case?

Comment: See also: "[Should I mention incorrect information on my CV?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/16884/should-i-mention-incorrect-information-on-my-cv)", "[Interview: Should I admit to a typo on my resume?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/32301/interview-should-i-admit-to-a-typo-on-my-resume)", and "[How To Request An Erronous Resume Be Updated Or Removed](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/76501/how-to-request-an-erronous-resume-be-updated-or-removed)"

Comment: @DavidK I want to know how to speak with HR about my mistake. And how to decrease its negative effect.

Comment: Max, did you look at all of the questions I linked? I believe that between the four questions I provided, at least one of them should answer your question.

Comment: @DavidK Yes, I looked all questions and answers. Some of them were hepful. But i edited my question to make it more specific.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> If I will get an interview, how should I address this mistake?

I would suggest you simply tell a potential employer *when* they call you for the initial phone screening or to set up the first face to face about the error.  **Honesty is the best policy here**, and most likely the mistake will be brought to light at some point anyway though background check or phone screening.

Another option for consideration is **you could proactively send** the companies that have the resume with errors an updated version.

I prefer the first option because if they are interested enough to contact me, I believe I can sell myself better **directly** versus sending a corrected resume.

Some folks are not that confident, which is why the second option is offered.

Comment: Why do you prefer that?

Comment: I guess the best approach of the 2 depends on your confidence then? :)

Comment: @AFriendlyGuy So, what is your advice? Send the updated version to the manager? What should I do in the case of the online application via company site?