# I made a mistake on length of employment

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process, applications

I applied to a job as a mental health service case manager, I honestly did not think I was going to get the job and the interview process has been intense. They told me to submit an application aside from my Resume. The application said to list 3 previous jobs, I put the correct dates for the first two, but on the last one I put my Start date as 2015 without thinking honestly. I don't even remember the exact year I started it was either late 2016 or early 2017 (it was a bad time mental health wise lol). I was working two jobs when I worked at the particular district that I listed and the first job I did have I worked in 2015 so I did not think twice about it I sort of just submitted the application and thought nothing of it.

Well fast forward and 1 interview, 2 essays, 3 reference checks and 4 exams later, they want to offer me the job I just need to provide the name and phone number of HR Staff for these 3 companies to verify employment dates and titles. Here lies the problem, I wish I would have been more meticulous on the dates but I wasn't and now I am not sure if I should tell the hiring manager of my oversight (the application was submitted like 3 weeks ago) or just hope they don't make a big deal out of it although I am sure they will as I did not pass only one of the 4 exams and they are offering me a different position than the one I applied for with less pay which is fine bc it is more than I make now but yeah... Am I pretty much just screwed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mistake in years of work in resume](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/107266/mistake-in-years-of-work-in-resume)

Comment: Your statements don't seem to add up. You say you don't remember when you started that job, but now that they want to check the dates all of a sudden you remember that they are wrong? How and when did you realise you had provided the wrong start date?

Answer (score 5):

Best thing to do is to just clarify your mistake. If you don't and they find out (and if they contact the HR of that company they will find out), they might think you intentionally lied and your chances will be gone (and you might end up on their blacklist). If you just tell the truth that you made a mistake, they might not really care (everyone makes mistakes). However they still might not feel like your fit for the job after.

I wouldn't say you're definitely screwed, but there is certainly a possibility this door closes. Still, clarifying the mistake seems like the best thing to do to me.

Comment: It sounds like @mohime has lots of experience in the mental health sector.  If the company has a problem with a small delta, between the actual dates and what you provided, then they were more than likely not seriously considering you in the first place. This isn't to say you shouldn't **immediately** fix your resume to indicate the actual dates you worked at those companies.  If you don't remember, you should call the company, and find out yourself so you can find accurate information.  Providing the same information in the future would just be carelessness on your part. Clarify your mistake.